# Storeing query result as table in big query retains its original tables's schema structure?

Tags: google-bigquery

My goal is to update all the rows of google BigQuery table. But to do so I have to recreate tables from older data with adding new column. So I run a select query with all the fields and some hashing and encoding/decoding function. and then storing output as new table and same name as older one with dropping old table. But my question is when I create a new table will it retain its original schema structure specially when original has some nested structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the job make sure you do not flatten results and the nesting of the schema will be retained.  You can compare the schemas of the original and new table within the web ui.

Comment: How to make sure that I do not flatten the result as I am totally new to BigQuery. Thank you

Comment: If you are using the web ui, choose 'show options', set your table name to write to, then select 'allow large results' and then untick 'flatten results'.  If you are using the API, there is a flatten_results=false parameter you can set, or something similar to that.